# Is there any SharedPreferences reset condition except the removal of an app?

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I'm using React Native to build an android/ios app. I'm using `expo-secure-store` with the bare React Native app and `expo-secure-store` saves data in SharedPreferences as encrypted on Android.

After I was updating my app, I received many reports from users that their data in SharedPreferences are reset and lost. On iOS, I didn't get such reports.

Is there any condition to reset data saved in SharedPreferences except the removal of the app?

As far as I know, data saved on SharedPreferences remains during its update. Is it wrong? I could not find any answer from the documentation. Please let me know about it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharedPreferences data survives updates, but if the new app version expects different keys or value types, the new version of the app may not be able to read the information correctly.

Apart from app uninstall, the user can delete the application data which will also remove the SharedPreferences data.

Comment: I never saw a format change. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @blackapps I meant, if the new app version expects different keys for example.

Comment: Then still the old ones would survive.

Comment: @blackapps yes sure, I edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Now that we are in it: `the new version of the app may not to able to read them correctly.` That does not happen as the keys are not there then.